# sql - copy data from another table that include partitions

Tags: oracle

Im looking to copy data from one table to another, I use Oracle pl/sql, I understand the simple statement

```
insert into cc_staff_2
select * from cc_staff
```

This selects all columns from CC_staff and places them in to CC_staff_2. However, both tables have different partitions in them. so for example

I created CC_staff with a partion

```
    CREATE TABLE CC_STAFF
    (           CCS_STAFF_SK        NUMBER (38),
                CCS_NAME            VARCHAR2 (30),
                CCS_BIRTH_DATE      DATE,
                CCS_GENDER          VARCHAR2 (1),
                CCS_MAR_STATUS      VARCHAR2 (20),
                CCS_OFFICE_SK       NUMBER (38),
                CCS_SALARY          NUMBER (38))
    PARTITION BY RANGE (CCS_SALARY)
    (PARTITION  SAL_20      VALUES LESS THAN (20000),
    PARTITION   SAL_30  VALUES LESS THAN (30000),
    PARTITION   SAL_50  VALUES LESS THAN (50000))
```

and then Created Cc_Staff_2 as the same table but with a different partition

```
    CREATE TABLE CC_STAFF
    (           CCS_STAFF_SK        NUMBER (38),
                CCS_NAME            VARCHAR2 (30),
                CCS_BIRTH_DATE      DATE,
                CCS_GENDER          VARCHAR2 (1),
                CCS_MAR_STATUS      VARCHAR2 (20),
                CCS_OFFICE_SK       NUMBER (38),
                CCS_SALARY          NUMBER (38))
    PARTITION BY LIST (CCS_OFFICE_SK)
    (PARTITION  NEWC        VALUES (561),
    PARTITION   LEED        VALUES (562),
    PARTITION   SHEF        VALUES (563))
```

I manually put in data to CC_Staff and now wish to copy this data over to CC_Staff_2. As you can see the columns are the same bar the two last columns with different partitions.

the error message I get is:

> ORA-14400 - inserted partition key does not map to any partition

Comment: So if i duplicate the table, copy the data over too. Then delete the old partition in the new table and add the new partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have values in the column `CCS_OFFICE_SK` of the first table different from 561, 562, 563.

You can handle it by creating a partition for every possible value on `CCS_OFFICE_SK` or by adding a default partition.

Say you have the value 999 in `CCS_OFFICE_SK`, you would need:

```
CREATE TABLE Cc_Staff_2
    (           CCS_STAFF_SK        NUMBER (38),
                CCS_NAME            VARCHAR2 (30),
                CCS_BIRTH_DATE      DATE,
                CCS_GENDER          VARCHAR2 (1),
                CCS_MAR_STATUS      VARCHAR2 (20),
                CCS_OFFICE_SK       NUMBER (38),
                CCS_SALARY          NUMBER (38))
    PARTITION BY LIST (CCS_OFFICE_SK)
    (PARTITION  NEWC        VALUES (561),
    PARTITION   LEED        VALUES (562),
    PARTITION   SHEF        VALUES (563),
    PARTITION   p_999       VALUES (999))
```

Or, if you don't want to check all the possible values of `CCS_OFFICE_SK`, you could use a default partition for values different from 561, 562, 563:

```
CREATE TABLE Cc_Staff_2
    (           CCS_STAFF_SK        NUMBER (38),
                CCS_NAME            VARCHAR2 (30),
                CCS_BIRTH_DATE      DATE,
                CCS_GENDER          VARCHAR2 (1),
                CCS_MAR_STATUS      VARCHAR2 (20),
                CCS_OFFICE_SK       NUMBER (38),
                CCS_SALARY          NUMBER (38))
    PARTITION BY LIST (CCS_OFFICE_SK)
    (PARTITION  NEWC        VALUES (561),
    PARTITION   LEED        VALUES (562),
    PARTITION   SHEF        VALUES (563),
    PARTITION   P_DEFAULT   VALUES (DEFAULT) )
```

Comment: Thanks, the only values I have in 'CCS_OFFICE_SK' are 561, 562 and 563. But i've added a deafult partition and its copied over the data.

Thanks